# Is there a 2 player variation of any of Sevens/Fan Tan/Domino?

Tags: sevens, shedding

And in particular, when you play with 2 players do you deal out all the cards the from the deck? Or is there some undealt part that players draw from during the game? I mean, if you deal them all then you'll just know what's in your opponent's hand?

This is going to sound trivial, but actually it's part of this theory/hypothesis I have for this anime/manga series [The Quintessential Quintuplets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quintessential_Quintuplets), where I think the game Sevens(/Fan Tan/Domino) is symbolic of something in the series (namely something to do with the number 7). My thought is that the card game Sevens (and thus the number 7) is so important that it even leads to a mistake like this. So if this were a mistake, then it's possible that Sevens is really important. Or something.

From S02E12:

[image]

The 2 kids pictured above are playing

- in the English dub version: 'Sevens'. (This is also in the English subtitles for the Japanese version.)
- in the original Japanese version: '[Shichi Narabe (7並べ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_(card_game)#Japan)', which is what Wikipedia calls a(/the?) Japanese variation of Sevens. In the upper right part of the Wikipedia page, you can see that it says 3-8 players, so I guess that includes the Japanese Sevens.

You can even see how the cards are laid out that they really are playing (some variation of) Sevens.

Other notes:

1. I've read only a bit of the manga, but I'm pretty sure no other kids were playing with the 2.
2. Additionally, Sevens has been played earlier in the series ([S01E09](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RReaF.jpg) where it's still Shichi Narabe [7並べ], but it's translated as 'Fan Tan' instead of 'Sevens', again by both the English dub and the subtitles for the original Japanese), but there were at least 3 players then.

Comment: You should split this out into questions for each game as a question should be limited to one thing.

Comment: @JoeW There's only 1 game here...just several variants. Any 2-player variant of any variant of Sevens is an answer. Does that make sense?

Comment: If there is only one game you should only have a single game tag and not tags for what appear to be 5 different games. Please remove any tags but what the game is largely known as.

Comment: @JoeW ok done. thanks. How do I make fan-tan, domino, etc as synonyms of sevens?

Comment: There is no reason to make them one unless those tags start getting used elsewhere

Comment: Cross-posted from Anime.SE: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66802/are-there-japanese-2-player-variations-of-sevens-fan-tan-domino-shichi-narabe-7