# In Sevens, why don't I just use up all my passes? (And consequently why isn't Sevens pure luck?)

Tags: game-theory, sevens, shedding

In the game of Sevens, also known as Fan Tan/Card Dominoes/[Shichi Narabe (7並べ)](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/57425/is-there-a-2-player-variation-of-any-of-sevens-fan-tan-domino), whenever there are options to pass, why wouldn't I just use up all my passes at the start regardless of what my opponents do?

Please give an example of a hand in 4-player Sevens where all the cards are dealt and there's no joker and all the sevens are played after the cards are dealt.

**Context**: I am trying to see how Sevens isn't just pure luck.

1. Case 1: I understand if there are no passes, then it's indeed a pure luck game.
2. Case 2: If there are no passes and if it's optimal to use all my passes at the start, then we just get Case 1.

Or please just tell me where I can read about this. My google-fu is currently failing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is long time ago that I played sevens, but I will try:

If you pass 3 times regardless what you opponents do and then on your next turn you cannot play a card you lose the game. So that is never a good idea. Also what do you think is your benefit when everyone lies down his cards while you are doing nothing?
Passing even if you can lay down a card is only a good idea when you know you can lay down a card next turn.

For Example:

You have 6 and 8 of spades. No one but you can lay a card on the 7 spades street. This you can use tactical for example everything is played except hearts 8 and up.Say you have 8 hearts and King of hearts. You techically cannot win the game because your King will be the last card to play. But if you do not play the 8, your opponents are forced to pass. When you have more time-outs then them you can just out-pass them and win the game. So it is a good idea to spare you time-outs and do not waste them on your first turns.

Comment: ok the 8 and king of hearts example i believe answers the question. thanks Marc90!

Comment: hi Marc90 i posted an answer. please lemme know what you think, for hopefully at least part1: i just think of a version of sevens with only 12 cards: sevens, sixes and fives.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by these:

1. Poker can be simplified to [Kuhn poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuhn_poker).
2. The Monty Hall problem is easy to understand if instead of 3 doors, you have 100 doors and then Monty opens all but 1.

## Part 1

I think of a simplified version of sevens where there are only 12 cards: fives, sixes and sevens.

- Assume also: 1 pass per player, 4 players, no jokers, all the sevens removed before cards are dealt and you 1st.
- Suppose each player gets 1 five and 1 six of the same suit.

Now it's unnecessary to pass because if you play your six, then you're not helping the others' finish their hands.

Case 1: Suppose you pass. Then the other 3 players play their six. Then you have to play your six. Then they all play their five. Finally, you lose.

Case 2: Suppose you play your six. No matter what the others do, you'll win.

## Part 2

I'm not really bothered to continue generalising until we reach the whole deck and add 2 more passes. I think I get the idea:

2A. Conjecture, which if true might be the 'fundamental theorem of sevens' similar to the [fundamental theorem of poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_poker):

> If you have a safe card but pass instead of playing, then you just waste time to clear your hand.

2B. I believe the contrapositive is:

> A pass means the player has no safe cards or is making their own situation worse.

Ah well maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think there's any [slow playing kinda trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_play) here: like you pass even though you have safe cards and then this somehow tricks your opponent

## Part 3:

Conclusion: When do you pass?

You pass either because you're forced to or because you're trying to not play a non-safe card... I guess.